# Deserialize request body to specific class instead of JsonObject

Tags: vert.x

Say we have this:

```
   Router router = Router.router(vertx);
   router.put("/products/:productID").handler(this::handleAddProduct);
```

and this:

```
 private void handleAddProduct(RoutingContext ctx) {
    String productID = ctx.request().getParam("productID");
    HttpServerResponse response = ctx.response();
    JsonObject product = ctx.getBodyAsJson();
    products.put(productID, product);
    response.end();
 }
```

my question is - how can we deserialize `ctx.getBodyAsJson()` to a specific Java class instead of the generic `JsonObject` class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use [`JsonObject.mapTo(Class)`](https://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/core/json/JsonObject.html#mapTo-java.lang.Class-), e.g.:

```
JsonObject product = ctx.getBodyAsJson();
Product instance = product.mapTo(Product.class);
```

*UPDATE*

you can customize the (de)serialization behavior by manipulating the `ObjectMapper` instance(s) associated with the `Json` class. here are some examples:

```
// only serialize non-null values
Json.mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);

// ignore values that don't map to a known field on the target type
Json.mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
```

keep in mind `Json` holds a reference to two different `ObjectMapper`s:

- `mapper`, and
- `prettyMapper`

Comment: thanks I wonder if this throws an error if there's missing fields or extra fields?

Comment: Vert.x uses Jackson under the covers, so you can take advantage of the full Jackson API to achieve your desired behavior. I've updated my answer with some examples.